# Push to root View controller in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I have hierarchy of `ViewControllers` in my storyboard structure.
It is **A-B-C-D**. **A** is embed with `NavigationController` and the flow goes on till **D** `viewController`. All fours view attached through segues. Now I am on **D** `viewController`, I defined some action to the button of **D** that It should take me directly to **A** `viewController` that is `rootViewController` or **B** `viewController`. Then how can I achieve this. I tried everything but didn't succeed.

I want something like it should not disturb **A-B-C-D** flow and it should take me to **A** `viewController` from **D**.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your D viewcontroller and drag i to your A viewcontroller.

Then click on the object which appears on the line you just created.

Write something like DtoA in the storyboard segue identifier in the attributes inspector.

Now in D view controller, just do:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DtoA" sender:self];
```

And if you instead wish to pop to a previous viewcontroller the old fashioned way, like from D to B:

```
UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
UIViewController* Bviewcontroller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[navController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: there is also `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)]` which will just take you back to A

Comment: @Fonix Yeah, I forgot to mention that.